# How to do DB migration from id to uuid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have table called charges which has fk of **prev_charge_id**

We have created new column **prev_charge_uuid** now want to convert **prev_charge_id** to **prev_charge_uuid**, what will be the efficient way to do it

DB columns

```
id name prev_charge_id prev_charge_uuid uuid
1  kv   null          null            abcd-abcd-abcd-abcd
2  Op   1             null            qbcd-aqcd-qbcd-qbcd
```

Have table like this
want prev_charge_uuid to get updated based on prev_charge_id

```
id name prev_charge_id prev_charge_uuid     uuid
1  kv   null          null                  abcd-abcd-abcd-abcd
2  Op   1             abcd-abcd-abcd-abcd   qbcd-aqcd-qbcd-qbcd
```

Comment: I think you can use [UPDATE FROM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-update.html) here.

Comment: UPDATE
  subscription_charges 
SET
  prev_charge_uid = c.uid 
FROM
  subscription_charges AS c
WHERE
  c.prev_charge_id = subscription_charges.id;

I am using this, but its not efficient way as million of rows are present

Comment: If by "efficient" you mean sub-linear (O(N)) time, then it's impossible. You do have to look up a row for each row in the table.

Answer (score -2):

To do what you are requesting is not a good idea. It violates the database design principle that data should be represented in exactly one place. In your example, you could run into problems if a uuid gets changed, but the prev_charge_uuid does not.

A much better strategy is to define the method in the model:

```rb
def prev_charge_uuid
  self.class.find(prev_charge_id).uuid
end
```

[update] I just noticed that prev_charge_id is a column in the table, so you can just use it iso calculating previous id... solves the problem that @sergio points out when there are "holes" in the id sequence.

Comment: Realistically though, that uuid is very unlikely to change. And your proposed solution is a forced N+1 problem. Not to mention the assumption that all the charges are always linked sequentially (1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> ...) and there are no holes in the sequence

Comment: @SergioTulentsev as you correctly observed in a previous comment, you always have to look up a another row. So "N+1 problem" is inevitable.

Comment: No, they are looking up that row one time, when they are writing that prev_charge_uuid in a data migration.